# How can i reorganize json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have:
json -

```
{"names":[{"name": 12,"y": 555}, {"name": 21,"y": 666}, {"name": 35,"y": 777}]}
```

2) structure for "name" -

```
12: "somestring", 21: "somestringlalala", 31:"lallaallla";
```

So, i need to change value of name with this structure. After this i must get -

```
{"names":[{"name": "somestring","y": 555}, {"name": "somestringlalala","y": 666}, {"name": "lallaallla","y": 777}]}
```

How can i do this? 
I know that i can use "for" and check every "name" value with if, but it's very newbie way, as i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The **`forEach()`** method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var data = { "names": [{ "name": 12, "y": 555 }, { "name": 21, "y": 666 }, { "name": 35, "y": 777 }] },
    replacements = { 12: "somestring", 21: "somestringlalala", 31: "lallaallla" };

data.names.forEach(function (a) {
    a.name = replacements[a.name];
});

console.log(data);
```

ES6 with [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var data = { "names": [{ "name": 12, "y": 555 }, { "name": 21, "y": 666 }, { "name": 35, "y": 777 }] },
    replacements = { 12: "somestring", 21: "somestringlalala", 31: "lallaallla" };

data.names.forEach(a => a.name = replacements[a.name]);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thnx! what do u think about Rob's answer?

Comment: map returns an array, which is superfluous.

Comment: Yep, agreed.  Thought of that right after I posted, used to just using map to get a new array with formatted data, but in this case I'm just modifying the original one.  forEach is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the name as the key to get the proper string like:

```
let names = [{name: 12}, {name: 31}, {name: 31}];
let nameKey = {12: "somestring", 21: "somestringlalala", 31:"lallaallla"}

names.map(nameObj => nameObj.name = nameKey[nameObj.name]);
console.log(names);
```

Here's a working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7zrd0xat/

Comment: Thnx for help, Rob. I marked Nina's answer's coz it's simply for me, but i'll try ur version too!

Comment: They are basically the same answer